# How to solve Jumping on the Clouds from Hacker Rank? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the [Jumping on the Clouds problem from Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem), but even though it passes the Sample Test cases, it fails when submitting the code.

My code is as follow:

```
function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
    
    var current;
    var next;
    var jumps = 0;
    let potentialNext;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
       current=c[i];
       next=c[i == c.length -1 ? 0 : i+1];
       
       if(!next && next === 0){
            jumps++;
            potentialNext = c[ i == c.length -1 ? 0 : i+2];

           if(potentialNext !== undefined && potentialNext === 1){
               i = i + 1;
           }
           
           if(potentialNext !== undefined && potentialNext === 0){
               i = i + 3;
           }
       }
       
       if(next !== undefined && next === 1){
           jumps++;
           i = i + 2;
       }
              
    }
    return jumps;

}
```

I can't figured what I am missing.

Comment: I tried to run your code and it does not pass the sample test case 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code didn't passed the *"Sample Input 0"*. It returned 3, where 4 was expected.
I have modified your code, and it works for all input cases. I have left comments at places explaining the code.

```js
function jumpingOnClouds(c) {

  var current;
  var next;
  var jumps = 0;
  let potentialNext;

  let i = 0;

  while(i < c.length){                          //Use a while loop, since it gives more control on adding a dynamic value to a variable. 
    current = c[i];
    if(i+2 < c.length && c[i+2] == 0){          //check if 2 clouds ahead from current index is jumpable or not 
      i+=2;                                     //Set the current index to 2 places ahead
      jumps += 1;                               //Make one jump 
    } else if(i+1 < c.length && c[i+1] == 0){   //Else Check if next cloud is jumpable or not 
      i+=1;                                     //set current index to index of next cloud
      jumps += 1;                               //Again, make one jump
    } else i+= 1;                               //If none of above if conditions are satisfied, add 1 to index. 
  }


  return jumps;

}

console.log(jumpingOnClouds([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]))  //Sample Input 0
console.log(jumpingOnClouds([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]))  //Sample Input 1
```

Comment: Yes, it does works. Although, I was hoping to see what I was missing on my code. Thanks for the commented code, though.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished this task and this is my code. I hope this can help you and I will explain the idea in comments. And I very appreciated if someone can tell   me the more efficient code. Thank you.

```
function jumpOnTheClouds(c){

    let path1 = []; //variable for 1 jump
    let j = 0;      //variable for index path1
    let path2 = []; //variable for potential jump 
    let k = 0;      //variable for index path2
    let jump = 0;   //variable for jump count
    for(let i = 1;i < c.length;i++){  //I use for loop to count with +1 jump only, and start in index 1 because starting point always index 0 
        if(c[i] == 0){                
            path1[j] = i ;            //If cloud not a thunderhead (0), path1 index j = index cloud 
            j++;                      //Set for next path1 index
        }
    }
    for(let i = 1;i < c.length;i++){  //I use this for loop to count potential jump.
        if(c[i + 1] == 0){            //Check if 2 clouds ahead not a thunderhead (0)
            path2[k] = i + 1;         //If 2 clouds ahead not a thunderhead (0), path2 index k = index cloud
            i += 1                    //Set index where we now
            k++;                      //Set for next path2 index
        }else if(c[i] == 0){          
            path2[k] = i;             //If 2 clouds ahead is thunderhead (1), path2 index k = index cloud
            k++;                      //Set for next path2 index
        }
    }
    if(path1.length > path2.length){  //Screening for the less jump
        jump = path2.length;
    }else{
        jump = path1.length;
    }
    return jump;
}
```